# How do you SELECT on a table with a ternary relationship?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm working on a learning project by designing a database for a library. The library lends books, videos, and audio. I decided for the fun of it to model people who contribute to a work as a ternary relationship. This makes it easier for, say, Quentin Tarrantino to be a Director, Author, and Actor in the same movie as well as be an author of some books, all w/o redundancy of people and the roles they play in creating a work.

I've called the three basic entities involved Contributors, Roles, and Works.

I'm having a problem because I'm uncertain what I'm supposed to do even in a simple case of listing a book. Will I end up with a separate row for each Contributor/Role pair? Or is there a way instead to have the resulting talbe have sort of "ad-hoc" columns (e.g. author, illustrator, translator for one book).

It feels like using this ternary relationship has injected hierarchy into my database and I'm wondering how this is best handled (without eliminating the ternary relationship, please).

[epilogue]
I got my query to work just fine. Stefan, I did have an intermediary table just so you (and other reading this) know. It looks like ternary relationships provide hours of fun for the application programmers.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't simply have a Contributors table and then use a foreign key from that table to your book, or video, or audio table?  It seems like you are making this overly complicated.

Comment: Also, if you are dead-set on going down this path, you would need an intersection table between your Contributors and Roles, as well as your Roles and works.  Since both of these are many to many relationships.

Comment: It sounds to me like he's doing it right.  It might help to show your table structure in code (i.e. your create table statements or just the basic table definitions.)

Comment: Stefan, I agree it could be modeled more directly and simply, but here are my reasons: First, I wanted to learn how a ternary relationship worked in code. Second, I don't have separate tables for book/video/etc.--instead I'm using a specialization hierarchy to subclass. Third, it seemed like it would eliminate redundancy--now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really have ad-hoc columns, because there can be different number of rows in each. E.g. a book may have one author, three illustrators and no translators.

To get a list of contributors to a book, you'll have to select all role-contributor pairs related to it, maybe sorting by role first, for easier grouping, and then group contributors by role and show on your page.

To edit data for a book, you'll have to validate that contributors of required roles exist (e.g. at least one author). This can partially be done by a ON UPDATE and ON DELETE triggers that won't allow to remove the last remaining author; for insertion you'll need something else.

Also I'd use a 'template' table that would list possible roles for each type of work `(work_type, role_type, is_required)`. If `is_required` is true, the role must be present in a valid work, if false, the role is allowed but optional. Only roles explicitly listed in the table for given `work_type` are allowed (so you don't have a composer for a book or illustrator for a musical track).

Comment: Thanks, you answered my main question and gave me some tangible ideas on how to proceed if I take it on to develop a front-end app.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefan H pointed out, you do need 1 more connecting table.  You're reducing redundancy by having a contributors table, but it looks like you're going to be hard coding the roles into the joining table between them.  You want to abstract out the roles as well, so your tables should look like:

```
Contributor
    ContributorID PK
Role
    RoleID PK
Work
    WorkID PK
ContributorRoleInWork
    ContributorRoleInWorkID PK
    (
        ContributorID FK
        RoleID FK
        WorkID FK
    ) --These three form a unique alternate key as well
```

To answer your actual question, yes, you're going to get a row back for every ContributorRoleInWork, but that's what you want.  When you're listing information for a book, you want one line back for each contributor/role combination.  To ease displaying the information, you can order/group by either contributor or role, depending on how you want to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, yes, you will end up with a separate row for each Contribute/Role, so for example, if 
John Doe is both the Executive Producer and Director of the film called Foo.

```
            WORK             CONTRIBUTOR           ROLE
            Foo              John Doe             Director
            Foo              John Doe             Executive Producer
```

So you'd have four tables (one per entity and the linking table):

```
          WORKS
          CONTRIBUTORS
          ROLES
          WORKS_CONTRIBUTORS
```

The linking table's primary key is a triad:

```
          WORKS_CONTRIBUTORS
          workid
          contributorid
          roleid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the simplest solution (not the optimal one though):

```
books           roles       people

ID              Role         ID
Name            BookID       Name
[other info]    PersonID     [Other info]
```

This way, if you want to know all the contributors in a given book ant their roles you can use an implicit join and

```
SELECT * FROM people,roles WHERE roles.BookID = [your book id] AND people.ID = roles.PersonID
```

Likewise, to get all contributions of a given person you could

```
SELECT * FROM books, roles WHERE roles.PersonID = [your person id] AND books.ID = roles.BookID
```

Instead, if you'd like to get only films directed by someone:

```
SELECT * FROM books, roles WHERE roles.PersonID = [your person id] AND roles.Role = "director" AND books.ID = roles.BookID
```

There are better ways to write these queries: get a reference manual for your SQL dialect and look for JOINs.